# Can I pay for an upgrade to Lion and get Mountain Lion free later?

Tags: upgrade, macos

I currently have Snow Leopard and do iOS development. I'm wanting to play with the new iOS 6 SDK, but I need to have Lion installed. Is it possible for me to pay for a Lion upgrade now and later get a Mountain Lion upgrade for free later?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, but you can upgrade right from 10.6 Snow Leopard to 10.8 Mountain Lion when Mountain Lion ships next month (for $20 USD), without having to spend the extra $30 USD to go from 10.6 Snow Leopard to 10.7 Lion.

Comment: Mountain Lion is coming out in July, which means 6 weeks max. So balance that against $30 that you'd pay for Lion (especially if you have computers you can't upgrade to MTLion which could use Lion).